# How to combine TypeScript output into multiple files in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compilation, typescript

I'm working on a web application which contains multiple SPA (AngularJS) applications, the front end code is TypeScript. I like the VisualStudio feature which combines JavaScript output into one file as I don't want too many JavaScript files. Is there a way to configure it so it still combines the files, but creates a few of them, one per SPA, let's say on folder basis?

I'd preferably like it done by VS, without any external tools.

Thanks

Comment: I've created an issue on TypeScript's Github that related to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for sure. Currently, there are two options which are widely accepted (sorry for lay-out, markup does not seem to love me):

1. **ASP.NET Bundles** (in Visual Studio by default, `.\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` - for more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862):

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr")
          .Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap")
          .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap/3.0.0/bootstrap.js",
                   "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
   ```
2. **`gulp-concat`** (external, but quite easy to implement):

   ```
   /** bundle and uglify app JS output files. */
   gulp.task('bundle-app-uglify', ['compile-app'], function () {
       // concat and uglify source scripts
       gulp.src(config.allAppJsFiles)
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(concat(config.appBundleNameMinified))
           .pipe(header(config.libraryHeaderTemplate, { 
               organization : config.libraryOrganization,
               url: config.libraryUrl,
               license: config.libraryLicense,
               version: config.libraryVersion,
               currentDate: new Date().toISOString()
           }))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bundleFolder));
   });
   ```